# Sum returns the correct answer... Sometimes

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, sum, left-join

I have the follow SQL that returns the correct answer until the second table has a match. There should be only a "1" in any of the returns but I get 2's and 3's in various places. I have 3 different dates in the tables and sometimes when it encounters something in the PA Sim Cnt affects the return in the 2 Mtr Cnt.

```
SELECT [Membership tbl].[Call Sign], Sum(IIf([2 Meter Net tbl].[Cur Date]=#9/15/2020#,1,0)) AS [2 Mtr Cnt], Sum(IIf([PA Simplex tbl].[Cur Date]=#9/15/2020#,1,0)) AS [PA Sim Cnt]
FROM ([Membership tbl] LEFT JOIN [2 Meter Net tbl] ON [Membership tbl].[Call Sign] = [2 Meter Net tbl].[Call Sign]) LEFT JOIN [PA Simplex tbl] ON [Membership tbl].[Call Sign] = [PA Simplex tbl].[Call Sign]
GROUP BY [Membership tbl].[Call Sign]
ORDER BY [Membership tbl].[Call Sign];
```

I have worked on this for several days and tried every combination I can think of.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: This seems a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. Write separate aggregations over appropriate rows and/or aggregate a case statement picking rows; join on a unique column set. Sometimes DISTINCT aggregation picks the right values after a non-key join. (A join on a non-key of either of 2 input tables can give multiple rows for each key of each table.)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to pre-aggregate in subqueries before joining, so each date is counted only once:

```
SELECT m.[Call Sign], mn.[2 Mtr Cnt], ps.[PA Sim Cnt]
FROM (
    [Membership tbl] m
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [Call Sign], Sum(IIf([Cur Date]=#9/15/2020#,1,0)) AS [2 Mtr Cnt]
        FROM [2 Meter Net tbl] 
        GROUP BY [Call Sign]
    ) mn ON m.[Call Sign] = mn.[Call Sign]
) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [Call Sign], Sum(IIf([Cur Date]=#9/15/2020#,1,0)) AS [PA Sim Cnt]
    FROM [PA Simplex tbl] 
    GROUP BY [Call Sign]
) ps ON m.[Call Sign] = ps.[Call Sign]
ORDER BY m.[Call Sign];
```

Comment: When I typed in the above it said.

Comment: Your query does not include the specified expression 'Call Sign' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: @Rang624: my bad, I forgot the `GROUP BY` clause in the first subquery. Fixed.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and this is so-o-o close I can taste it. First it queries me for the date parameter, second all the places it finds the date it puts in 0, I was expecting the sum. I later want to put between dates in and I was expecting 0 if it didn't find the Call Sign (it puts in blanks).

Comment: @Rang624: use `Nz()` to turn `null` values to `0`, like: `SELECT m.[Call Sign], Nz(mn.[2 Mtr Cnt], 0) as [2 Mtr Cnt], Nz(ps.[PA Sim Cnt], 0) as [PA Sim Cnt] FROM ...`

Comment: LOL, now everything is 0.

Comment: The Sum(IIf(mn.[Cur Date]=#9/15/2020,1,0)) statement is not behaving as I thought it would. I thought if the cur date = 9/15/2020 it would add 1 to the results. If I reverse the 1, 0 it counts all the call sign finds. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @Rang624: I think I spotted the last typos in the subquery (aliases should not be there).

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thank you so much. I have since added more table joins and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.[Call Sign], Nz(mn.[2 Mtr Cnt],0) AS [2 Mtr Cnt], Nz(ps.[PA Sim Cnt],0) AS [PA Sim Cnt]

FROM ([Membership tbl] AS m 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Call Sign], 
    Sum(IIf([2 Meter Net tbl].[Cur Date]=#9/15/2020#,1,0)) AS [2 Mtr Cnt] 
FROM [2 Meter Net tbl] 
GROUP BY [Call Sign])  AS mn ON m.[Call Sign] = mn.[Call Sign]) 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Call Sign], 
    Sum(IIf([PA Simplex tbl].[Cur Date]=#9/15/2020#,1,0)) AS [PA Sim Cnt] 
FROM [PA Simplex tbl] 
GROUP BY [Call Sign])  AS ps ON m.[Call Sign] = ps.[Call Sign]

ORDER BY m.[Call Sign];
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally poor. Explain why it answers the question and/or solves or corrects its problem. [answer]